# SVN: Can you remove directories from a local checkout only (not from the repository)?

Tags: svn

Assume that you have a directory under subversion control, that contains some files and tons of subdirectories, like that:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
dir4/
:
dirXX/
```

Now you need the files and some of the dirs, but not all of them. This can be done with SVN. Just make the checkout non-recursive:

```
svn checkout -N <URL>
```

This checks out only the first directory and the files inside. No subdirectories are included. Even if you go into the checkout directory and run a "`svn up`", it will only update the files checked out previously, it will not add the directories. You can now selectively add the directories you need by explicitly updating those. E.g. if you need dir2 and dir4 only, you can go into the checkout directory and execute

```
svn up dir2
svn up dir4
```

If you run a generic "`svn up`" in the future, it will only update the files and those two directories, it will not add any of the other directories.

Now the problem: What if I decide at any later point that I don't need dir2 any longer? How do I get rid of it? There seems no way of doing so, other than deleting the whole checkout and start over from scratch.

When you just delete dir2, the next "`svn up`" will bring it back, as "`svn status`" of course shows it as missing now ("!" in front of its name). Running a "`svn remove`" will remove it of course, but on next commit it will also remove it from the repository, which must not happen.

Even the new sparse directory ("shallow checkout") feature of SVN 1.5 is of no use here:

> Subversion 1.5's implementation of
>   shallow checkouts is good but does not
>   support a couple of interesting
>   behaviors. First, you cannot
>   de-telescope a working copy item.
>   Running svn update --set-depth empty
>   in an infinite-depth working copy will
>   not have the effect of discarding
>   everything but the topmost
>   directory—it will simply error out.
>   
>  - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html

Is this complete impossible with SVN? Anyone ever came up with a clever work-a-round to that?

Just creating the checkout directory (without SVN) and then checking out the individual subdirectories from the repository directly as subdirectories to this directory will work for the directories: now every directory is a checkout of its own, can be updated and once not needed any longer, you can just delete it. However, how do I get the files then (e.g. file1.txt)? SVN does not allow to checkout individual files, you can only checkout whole directories.

Comment: I think this is the same question as these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862950/subversion-prevent-local-modifications-to-one-file-from-being-committed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit

Comment: @ire_and_curses: First, why don't you write this as an answer? Second: These two questions are about preventing something from being committed. This has nothing to do with my problem at all. Even if I do svn delete on the directory and prevent this from being commited, the directory will not go away. Have you even read my question or just the headline?

Comment: @Mecki: I did read your question, although I admit in a hurry. I *thought* you were asking how to delete a version-controlled dir in the local copy without affecting the repository version, and without getting the dir back in the next update. Although I haven't tried it, it seems like making everything else a member of a changelist will do exactly that. I didn't write this as an answer because it already exists in both the other questions (which I thought were the same) - If I were right, I'd just be getting rep for someone else's work. Sorry if this is no use to you.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: If you don't write a real answer, you cannot get upvotes and I can not directly comment on what you write. Even if the question has been answered elsewhere, always write a real answer. If my question is then not closed as dupe in time, I can accept your answer as "the answer", even if it just directs me elsewhere. Not fair? I think it is. After all just answering by giving a link is also gives you rep for someone else's work.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

*What I'm trying to do cannot be done with Subversion 1.4 or Subversion 1.5; Period.
 No work around exists, that's just the way it is.*

**It can be done with Subversion 1.6, though.**

Unlike SVN 1.5, SVN 1.6 can **reduce the depth** on a directory

```
svn up --set-depth exclude dir2
```

is the solution. It sets the depth for dir2 to zero and it will immediately vanish from the checkout and no update will bring it back, unless you explicitly set the depth of this directory to a value again (or just do an update on it without depth option, since not giving any depth always means infinity, unless you use non-recursive, which means "files").

TIP:
Actually SVN 1.6 cannot really reduce the depth the same way it can increase it. You can increase it from any level to any higher level. You can only reduce it to "exclude" (the lowest level of all). If you want to reduce from "infinity" (highest) to "files" (somewhere in the middle), you must first reduce it to "exclude" (causing the directory to vanish) and then increase it back again to "files". This is a bit of a hack, but it works just nice.

Comment: +1 multiple directories can be excluded by giving space separated values. Example: svn up --set-depth exclude dir1 dir2 dir3

Comment: This didn't work for me after I had deleted the directory with rm. I had to revert it first and then run this command, but it was successful after that.

Answer (score 41):

For anyone who comes across this later, and uses **TortoiseSVN**, here is how to do the same thing...

1. Right-click on the folder that you *no longer want* checked out (this is the folder you want to exclude)
2. From the context menu, choose "TortoiseSVN > Update to Revision..."
3. In the window that pops up, set the "Update Depth" dropdown box to "Exclude"
4. Click "OK". SVN will automatically remove that directory from your drive now.

(Note: This was done with TortoiseSVN 1.7.5, and may vary for other versions.)

Answer (score 13):

Update: I'm running SVN 1.6.11 and I was able to de-telescope using `svn up --set-depth empty dir` rather that having to `exclude` the directory.

Answer (score 2):

With svn 1.6, `--set-depth` is the answer.

With svn < 1.6, you can get sparse checkouts by abusing `svn switch`: Create an empty directory somewhere in your repository, and `switch` the subdirectories you don't need right now to point to that instead of their "real" URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [trick](http://yoopergeek.blogspot.com/2007/11/cloakinghidingfiltering-unwanted.html) involving a local repository and svn:**externals** declarations.

Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting! First answer and already a very good one (upvote). Not sure if this is the best solution and if this really will solve my problem, but I should give this solution a try. Should this work and nobody has anything more simple to offer, I will accept this answer. Even if it won't solve my problem, it might solve some other SVN problems (so this knowledge is handy in any case)

Comment: Sorry, this cannot really solve my issue. I can make a local repository and just link in some of the subdirectories, so only those appear... and I can probably unlink them (removing the external declaration) and they will go away... but I have no way to get the files fileX.txt in the main directory, as you cannot link in single files, only directories and linking in this directory links in the files and all subdirectories of it :(