# how to remove working copy files after rights change on server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have some SVN projects with this folder structure

```
project/trunk/
project/branches/1.x
project/branches/2.x
project/branches/3.x
```

- First checkout, I have the RW rights on all branches, and checkout everything
- Then supopose that I change the rights on the server, and have only RW on branch 1.x, nothing on the others

-> If I delete on my working copy the branch 2 and 3, they appears as missing and every update recreate them (even if I don't have read rights on server, I suppose its some kind of local tortoisesvn cache)

-> If I make a clean checkout everything is ok, but it's obviously not what I want to do every time rights changes.

-> I could put all theses branches in ignored, but if rights change on server and I'm not aware of it, I won't have access to them unless I un-ignore them.

PS: clean up does not resolve anything in this case

Is there a way to force tortoise to synchronize my working copy, and avoid the "missing file" problem caused by the windows manual delete ?

Comment: The fundamental flaw here is that you have the entire repository checked out when it is expected you would have each branch checked out separately - which more than likely would only result in having maybe a couple of the checked out - like trunk, the feature branch youre working on, and a bigfix branch or something.

Comment: I see your point, but in our approach we have many different projects (many ~= 200) that are each a different shared library project (with trunk and branches). They are all in the same SVN Repository and share a common revision number, but this approach is a lot less complicated when we checkout.

Comment: Hmmm... i would probably go with `svn:externals` in that case :-)

Comment: very interesting, I did not know about svn:externals. I think I'm going to read more about this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 1.5, Subversion supports sparse checkouts. Instead of doing a full checkout of a repository, you can define the checkout *depth* per directory. It is also possible to change the *depth* settings at any point in time using `svn update`.

In your case, after you have lost the rights for `project/branches/1.x` you could remove it from your working copy using:

```
svn update --set-depth exclude project/branches/1.x
```

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439176).

Comment: Thank you, it did resolve my problem, but I wish there was a tortoiseSVN graphic menu to avoid the command line in windows.