# delete directory in SVN so that "svn up" won't restore that directory

Tags: svn

Let me give an example. Suppose I have a checkout directory named "mycheckout". Inside it, there are a lot of subdirectories and files. There is one subdirectory call "mysub", which I don't need but others may need. Certainly I can't do "svn rm mysub". But I would like to remove *mysub* so that next time when I do "svn up" from *mycheckout*, it won't be restored.

Is there anyway to achieve this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN: Can you remove directories from a local checkout only (not from the repository)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439176/svn-can-you-remove-directories-from-a-local-checkout-only-not-from-the-reposit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that when you checkout with [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).