# Subversion/TortoiseSVN: prevent local modifications to one file from being committed without deleting?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, ignore

I use TortoiseSVN, but I understand the same problem exists with command line svn.

I have a Java file and a few properties files which contain the default user, default database, etc.  I have changed these for my environment, and every time I commit, I have to go through the list of files and uncheck each of these.  Often, I forget, and have to revert these to the previous version when I forget.

I know about the ignore-and-commit functionality (called something different on command line), but it requires that you delete/unversion the file first.  Yes, like I'm really going to delete a file in my project and affect all other users and deployments.

How can I have my local changes not show up in the commit list, without a bunch of complicated scripts I see in some of the questions, which would probably not work for the GUI client anyway?

Wishing I used git, but my company just will not switch.

Note: this is *not* a duplicate of the following:

[Subversion: prevent local modifications to one file from being committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862950/subversion-prevent-local-modifications-to-one-file-from-being-committed)

[SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)

The OP in both cases accepted answers which will not work for my case.

Comment: You do *not* need to unversion files to add them to TortoiseSVN's `ignore-on-commit` changelist. From the [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html): `Changelists are purely a local client feature. Creating and removing changelists will not affect the repository, nor anyone else's working copy. They are simply a convenient way for you to organise your files.`

Comment: The reason that this is a duplicate is explained by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot; if you've got a *reason* why that won't work for you, you should tell us why so we can help you.