# SVN ignore that is local to working copy?

Tags: svn

Is there any way that I can ignore a file in my local working copy without polluting the svn properties?  I don't want my local ignore pattern (e.g. temp files) being published to repository and cause repo having lots of useless information.

Just like in git, I can have .git/info/exclude. Is there any similar way in SVN?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit

Comment: I found this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170219/4669135

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can put them into the changelist `ignore-on-commit`. See [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit).

EDIT: This only works with tortoisesvn and possibly other clients, not with *svn* per se.

Comment: Thanks.  In fact I know this method, but ignore-on-commit only works with svn 1.5+, and not every client is supporting it (e.g. Subclipse).

Comment: Though this method don't really suit my need but I think it is the best and most official answer for SVN.  Thanks  :)

Comment: Ignore-on-commit will not be published to other clients. [official reference](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html)

Comment: @Nickolas, **local** to working copy implies exactly that, yes.

Comment: The other question and answer you reference point out that ignore-on-commit does its magic only for the Tortoise GUI ... the svn command line will still, unfortunately, try to commit the files.

Answer (score 15):

Yes there is.
Goto TortoiseSvn Setting -> General.

There is a global ignore edit box. Add the following as a good starting point to ignore items you do not want to go into the repository:

```
*.fbl6 *.fbpInf *.fb6lck *.*scc *.aps *.bak *.cache *.eto *.ilk *.ncb *.obj *.patch *.pch *.plg *.rdl.data *.sbr *.sqlsuo *.suo *.svclog *.tlh *.tli *.tmp *.user *.vshost.* *DXCore.Solution [Bb]in [Dd]ebug [Oo]bj [Rr]elease _[Rr]e[Ss]harper.* _UpgradeReport_Files Ankh.Load Backup* CVS PrecompiledWeb svnignore[.-] [Tt]humbs.db UpgradeLog*.* _vti_* lint.db
```

Comment: Oh Yes! I almost forgot that the "global" ignore list is in fact "local" ("local" in the sense it is kept local and not synced to svn).  Thanks for reminding me for this! :)

However it effects on all working copies, for which I may want that file to ignore in one working copy but not in another.

Comment: I found this looking for how to ignore foo.vshost.exe - the pattern having `.vshost.` doesn't seem to work, I've now found that `*.vshost.*` works.

Answer (score 6):

This technique is more like `.gitignore` than `.git/info/excludes` ([Managing svn:ignore with impunity](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/managing-svn-ignore-with-impunity/)):

> - Create a `.svnignore` in the top of your project.
> - Make a list of files/wildcards you care to ignore
> - Save it
>
> Now, from the top of your project, you can do:
>
> ```
> $ svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore  .
> ```

At least this way you have to make just 1 `propset` change.

You'll still have to either track or ignore your `.svnignore` (just like `.gitignore`).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid downloading a remote directory completely, the following works:

`svn update --set-depth exclude <folder-to-ignore>`

Comment: This only works in order to *not download a remote directory* (e.g. I work on `local/widgets`, don't care to have `local/largelibrary`, I can set depth to exclude on largelibrary from local: largelibrary won't be ever synced, and conflicts will arise if I ever create it locally). Upvoting, since this is exactly my use case, where the other answers don't apply.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Iserni.  I believe that was my use-case as well where the repository was quite large and had many folders I simply didn't care about.  I've added that explanation into the answer.

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with the question

Comment: I landed at this question while looking for a way to do exactly what is described in this answer.