# How to locally ignore .git and .gitignore in a svn repo?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a SVN working copy (managed by TortoiseSVN). In that working copy I use git for local version control and branching. 
Of course, I want to hide the .git directory and .gitignore file for svn.

However, ignoring them means adding a property to the repository which is no longer local. 
I don't want that (as many people share this repo) as it is annoying since it is proposed to be committed on each commit to the repo.

I found (via that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)) the possibility of the ignore-on-commit list. But (at least in TortoiseSVN) it just works on files:
If I do a check for modifications the repo shows up with properties modified. However, I cannot add it to the ignore-on-commit as the context menu entry just does not show up.

So, is there a way (f.ex. by commandline?) to add the repo to the ignore-on-commit?

Are there other ways to hide/ignore the .git and .gitignore for svn?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `global-ignores` configuration option.  Which is documented in the [SVN Book's Ignoring Unversioned Items section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

This setting will impact all of your Subversion clients and working copies, but I suspect that ignoring .git and .gitignore on all checkouts is not an issue for you.

**Direct editing of the config file**

On Unix that setting would be applied to `~/.subversion/config` and on Windows it'd be `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` (though it can also be stored in the registry, [see the documentation in the SVN Book about that](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.windows-registry)).

The default will be commented out like so:

```
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
```

You just need to uncomment the lines and add `.git` and `.gitignore` to them.

**TortoiseSVN UI**

In your case you're using TortoiseSVN so you can avoid editing the file directly and use the settings within TortoiseSVN.  Under the ***General*** section there is a ***Subversion*** block with an edit block labeled ***Global ignore pattern***.  Just add `.git` and `.gitignore` to the list of patterns.  This is covered in the Global ignores block on the [Ignoring files and directories](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html) section and more specifically in the details on the **Global ignore pattern** setting in the [Settings section](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-main) of the TortoiseSVN documentation.