# how to ignore a committed file in subversion?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I joined my teammate to a existing project. There is a file I would like to ignore, as I have some changes which only fit my local machine. But seems SVN cannot ignore file which are already committed.

Does anyone have any suggestion if I would like to ignore that committed file in my machine?

I am using Mac.

Thanks all. Happy Thanksgiving. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4139882/426834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move that file to a different directory undersubversion and do not check out the new folder

so for example your source tree looks like

```
src/project/fileIdontWant
src/project/theRestofMyStuff
```

Create a new folder in a seperate folder

```
src/machineSpecific/fileIdontWant
src/project/theRestofMyStuff
```

Now only check out `src/project` from now on unless you want `src/machineSpecific` project

Comment: thank mate. the idea is ok. but it will affect the production server too. never mind. i am now ignore the file after moving it to somewhere else. and then go to production server and restore it. it's not really straight forward but at least it is a work around. :)