# Can I ignore a single file in Windows SVN?

Tags: windows, svn

I use TortiseSVN and when I "unversion & ignore a file", it will be removed on the server. There doesnt appear to be a "ignore".

[image]

How can I ignore a file (dont change the server copy) in SVN? I dont mind using Command Prompt, but on Windows theres no `svn` command. Or perhaps I need to find that executable 1st

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has an [ignore-on-commit](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-ignore) changelist, which you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Get [collabnet command line svn client](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/getit.html). They provide certified binaries. And have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139882/svn-ignore-a-file-but-include-it-in-checkout).