# How to do a "hijack", like in ClearCase, in Subversion?

Tags: svn, clearcase

In ClearCase you you can "hijack" a file which means that the change management system will let you make changes to it, but it won't try to commit those changes or try to update that file when you pull the lastest changes. This is useful for configuration files or hacking classes that are only needed for production (like a slow filter that encrypts messages etc).

Is there anyway to do this in Subversion?

Comment: The usecases for this feature looks terrible

Comment: @Simon if you go to the second link in my answer they admit there are times for this. Turning off validation or overriding settings to deploy faster while developing are common scenarios.

Comment: I did no see in the link anything that could justify breaking bits of your versioning system. The timestamp example is a not very convining one. Are there IDE that HAVE to mess up with your files? This look like a pretty bad feature to me.

Comment: Well where I was working RAD (IBM's flavour of Eclispse) was autogenerating files and some of us were using version 7 and some were using version 8 and the difference in the files was just in the comments. Sure, we could have rejiggered the ancient fragile build system, but that would have taken days, and you would have been personally responsible for any real or imagined regressions caused by this. So, it was easier to hijack the files than the constant noise of recommitting them. Also, we did this to config files to make our IDEs point different databases.

Comment: @Simon Actually just came across an even better use case: your `log4j.properties` file. Compared to production, when I deploy locally in dev, I like to increase the number of debug messages for the components I'm working on and decrease the ones that are orthogonal to that which I'm working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real equivalent in Subversion in that the files are directly writable in your working directory in Subversion.

You can ignore a [file in subversion on commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895548/subversion-ignore-modifications-to-a-file-locally-on-one-client-only) (with TortoiseSVN), which allows you to ignore current modifications done locally while keeping the file under version control.
And that is fairly similar to "hijacked" files in ClearCase.

---

The [OP ArtB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254477/artb) asked about a command-line solution, and I suggested [using changelist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/896258/6309) (as in [`svn changelist`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html)), which he summarized in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9317090/6309) (upvoted)

You will see this approach taken in:

- "[SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as “do not commit”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635684/6309)"
- "[svn ignore a file but include it in checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142123/6309)"

Comment: Seems familiar from the UI, but how does one do that from the command line?

Comment: @ArtB the question I referenced (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895548/subversion-ignore-modifications-to-a-file-locally-on-one-client-only) mentions alternatives (changelists: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a new answer to better summarise to what VonC helped lead me. The answer is to take the file and [add it changelist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html) called "[ignore-on-commit](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html)"(see: *Excluding Items from the Commit List*). So the svn command itself would be `svn changelist ignore-on-commit $target_file`.

Comment: Good point. +1. I have updated my answer for more visibility and added a couple of references to other similar answers.