# Visual Studio 2010 and Subversion

Tags: svn

I have VS2010 up and running with SVN integration using the AnkhSVN client which works well. I'm more used to working with Subversion with php projects on the LAMP stack and am unsure how to setup my VS2010 workflow to make it easy for 3 or 4 developers to work off the one Visual Studio solution.

A couple of quick queries someone might be able to help with.

1.) After I've setup my VS solution and project and completed the initial import/add to the SVN repo, what's the best way for Developer 2 to setup their machine? Should they create an empty VS solution with the same name and then checkout the source from the repo into the same directory on their local machine? Or should the contents of the repo be enough for VS2010 to open the project?

2.) What's the best way to maintain a list of ignored files which will never need to be managed via SVN (such as a web config file etc.)

3.) What VS files should NEVER be managed by a central SVN repo that need to be specific to an individual developers machine?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Ed

Comment: Which SVN are you using, Microsoft VisualSource Safe, tortoise SVN, AnkhSVN?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm using AnkhSVN per my original question - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is a client that embeds the svn commands into VS, it works on any svn working copy. All you have to do is open the project in VS. AnkhSVN will recognise that the files have the appropriate SVN links (i.e. in the `.svn` directories). You don't have to do any more than that!

Obviously you have to get the project files onto `dev2`'s workstation. My personal preference is to use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net) (it all works together quite nicely) to do a sparse checkout of the project directory, but you can use the `File | Open | Subversion Project` menu item to fetch the project from within VS.

To prevent files being committed once you've got one, use a changelist. There's a special one called [ignore-on-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit) which is a client-only feature so you won't affect the repo by using it.

Ignore files... remember to put them in a server-side hook in case someone commits without the right client-side ignore configuration. I ignore the following:

```
aps, vbw, obj, ncb, plg, bsc, ilk, exp, sbr, opt, pdb, idb, pch, ipch,   
sdf, res, suo, scc, *Debug, user, rar, cache, bin, log, Buildlog.htm, 
intermediate.manifest, ReSharper*, msi, *\obj\*, vshost.*, mt.dep, old, 
UpgradeLog.XML
```