# Can SVN be set up to emit a warning when comitting a file?

Tags: svn

Today I noticed that a week ago I had accidentally modified a file that I shouldn't and committed it with the rest of them. Which got me thinking, that it would be nice, if you could flag some files in SVN as "you probably don't want to commit this one". That is, if I do accidentally modify such a file, then at commit I would get a warning question: "Are you reeeeealy sure you want to commit this file?" I don't want a full lock, because there might be some rare legitimate cases for touching these files.

Can this be set up somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)

Comment: Similar, but not exactly. That guy wants to prevent the commit. I want a warning message, but an option to still go through.

Comment: That's exactly what the do not commit change-list does. It prevents you from committing by default, but you can override it.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with locks, you can add a lock to every file you want to think twice before committing with a special user you created only for this purpose (say *notSoFast*).

This way every time you try to commit a file that is locked by *notSoFast* you will be forbidden to do so, if you really need to update that file you can (a) commit this file logging as user *notSoFast* or (b) remove the lock from the user, commit your changes, then relock the file with user.

Answer (score 1):

I would second what @mtrovo has told you, here is another option which is much more difficult to implement:

TortoiseSVN allows you (I think from version 1.6.x) to use client hook scripts. Client hook scripts are called like the server side equivalent, but on the client side. You could there add some information to your files, and depending on that information, add a dialog that asks you if the storing of the information is appropriate. You have to do the following steps to get a working solution:

1. Add a client pre-commit hook. The reason for the pre-commit is, that the list of files is available, and the result of the pre-commit is true or false. So you may cancel if the user not explicitly allows to commit the files.
2. Add as svn:property to your files that should be checked before commited by the user. You could name it e.g. `svn:needs-ok` with some value.
3. Every time you want to commit something, it will be checked by your script, that

   - if a file has the property `svn:needs-commit`,
   - it will start a dialog with that information, and the buttons `OK` and `Cancel`.
4. Depending on the dialog answer, the script returns true or false.
5. You have to ensure that

   - all clients have installed your client pre-commit hook and
   - all files that need to be checked have that property `svn:needs-ok` set.

I don't think that this is a solution that works sufficient well to be worth the annoyance :-(

Comment: That's true. I was hoping for something more centralized. But if there is no such option, then this isn't so bad either.

Answer (score 1):

I have two [pre-commit hooks](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip) that might do what you want:

- The first is what I call my *Kitchen Sink* hook because it does a lot of stuff. One of the things you can specify is who is allowed to make changes to particular files. For example,you could set these files as *read-only* for most users, but still allow particular users to make modifications in them when required. It's all controlled by a control file, so you don't have to modify the script itself.
- The second hook is a notification hook that will allow users to specify what files they want to watch. If a watched file is modified, the user is sent an email. For example, the tech leads could watch these particular files, and get notification when these files were changed. If the developer was authorized to modify the file, they could ignore the issue. If the developer wasn't authorized to make the change, the change can quickly be reverted.

The first approach will prevent the change, but it means that if a change is required, making the change could be a pain since you have to ask a particular person to make the change. In the second approach, unauthorized changes could still take place, but whomever is responsible will quickly be notified and can revert the change. Normally, if a developer knows someone is watching them, they'll be more careful.

The hooks use Perl, but no non-standard modules, so there's no need to download and install modules from CPAN which can be difficult for some sites.

Comment: Also nice suggestions. For the first point I like maddoxej's version a bit better, but it's really the same thing anyway. The second one is novel (in this question) and noteworthy.

Answer (score 1):

For files that are already in version control and are not ignored, You could handle this using a pre-commit hook to reject the change, but allow an "excuse" in the comment that could disable the pre-commit hook. If the comment has the text "I'm sure because" then it would allow the commit.

Comment: Hehe, original! I like this. :)