# Eclipse Subversive commit changelist?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I just created an ignore-on-commit changelist as described in [SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit) and it's awesome on the command line, making it much easier to view the changes I care about in the command line.

Having all this power and organization now I select all my projects in eclipse and go to Team > Commit and there is no notion of changelists in the commit dialog and I still have to go through all the changes and tediously select which files to commit.

Am I missing something in Eclipse' Subversive that would allow me to use changelists in the commit dialog?

I found the following setting, but it doesn't seem to change anything...
[image]

Comment: Extremely interested to know how to get ignore-on-commit to work in Eclipse as well, using Subversive.

Comment: Obviously I've had no answer yet.  Because of that I'm doing most of my svn through command line these days.

Answer (score 3):

I see two possibilities here:

### **1. Using svn:ignore**

The easiest solution would be to add the files you don't want to commit to your `svn:ignore` list.

You can do it in Subversive through the *Team>Add to svn:ignore...* menu:

[image: svn:ignore menu in Subversive]

### **2. Using change sets**

The alternative is to :

- go in the *Synchronize* view
- click the *Show Change Sets* button
- you can then add changed files to change sets (and create new change sets) from the right-click menu.

You can find more information in the [Subversive documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php).

Comment: Wouldn't adding to svn:ignore require it to be checked in with the svn:ignore property set in order for it to take effect?  If so, that pretty much defeats the purpose.  I might have a look at the change sets.  Does that mean it uses its own change set mechanism instead of the one built in to svn?

Comment: Concerning `svn:ignore` you're right, but it could be an option if your are working on your own branch. You may consider using `global-ignores` also... For Subversive's Change sets, I don't know how they are handled internally, but I've seen them be used this way in the past...

Comment: Since the files I do not want to commit have changes local to my machine, but are still under source control, adding to svn:ignore isn't going to do my any good.  The changesets in the plugin are interesting, it's sad they don't appear to integrate with the svn built-in change lists.