# SVN Exclude files from current commit

Tags: svn, commit

I have a handful of files I wish not to commit to my SVN for the duration of this one commit while having the rest commit to the repository. Is there any SVN command that I can in a sense just ignore specified files for the commit I want to make?

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the link pointed out in the comments was helpful to a point, however what I ended up having to do was just commit files/folders specifically, working around the ones I didn't want to commit through

```
svn ci -m 'Message' folder/file
```

might not have been the most elegant method, but it worked, and has taught me a valuable lesson in making sure to commit frequently per moving piece/section before moving on to the next.