# How to exclude a lib file from build path in android without deleting from project

Tags: android, eclipse, build, compilation, apk

In my android_Project/libs/armeabi folder I have some *.so files which are included in the apk everytime it is built. Due to size constrains I do not want to include these files in my apk(I have commented out their functionality), but I cant delete these files from the project because its on SVN.
Is there anyway I can exclude these files from my apk without creating a diff svn branch or a diff local copy ?

Comment: In eclipse, right click your project, go to Build Path -> Configure Biuld Path... -> Libraries, remove unused dependencies from project's build path.

Comment: I believe that the solution lies in the SVN department: see *[SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as “do not commit”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)*.

Answer (score 1):

libraries in the libs folder are automatically included in the apk. try moving them outside the libs folder to a separate folder in your project directory.

incase you would like to add them back, you can move them back to the libs folder or specify their location in the build path.

Comment: Hi Gan, If I remove them from the libs folder I might disturb the SVN file structure. I am looking for a solution in which I change some code in the project and the lib file in excluded.

Comment: You can try deleting the library form the libs folder if you don't want to disrupt your SVN structure.