# SVN: commit all files but one

Tags: svn, commit

I have different files that must be committed to a repository. One file has some changes, but I don't want to commit also this one, because at the moment it has some dangerous changes. How can I tell svn files that I don't want to commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
svn changelist ignore-on-commit file-you-want-to-add
```

I hope this will help you 
[SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a client like TortoiseSVN you can check which files you would like to commit without committing the entire package.

Here is a link:

http://tortoisesvn.net/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm under Linux and I'm using the shell. I can't install anything on this computer.

Comment: If you don't have a ton of files you can simply append the only ones you want to the commit command. svn commit file_1 file_2.

Answer (score 0):

There are also excellent gui tools under Linux (I use kdesvn), but you can also do this on cli by temporarily adding the file in question to the svn-ignore list.

You can also experiment with the `find` utility. It is used to select files by attributes, so for example by name. And it offers a nogation switch: `find . ! -name "file-to-gnore"`. Maybe you can pipe the result to your cli svn client? Yes, you can: `find working_copy_folder ! -name "file-to-gnore" | svn ci`

Comment: I think users will have a bad time when they forget to remove files from svn:ignore and miss a commit.