# Ignoring versioned files: Can I "assume-unchanged" a file in SVN?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have a **versioned** file I want to change for local development, but I also want to make sure that I do not accidentally commit those changes to the SVN-Repository. I think in Git there is an option to mark a file with "assume unchanged". Does there exist a similar option in SVN? How do you usually handle this?

**Update**: Voted to close own question, as I've found it's a duplicate of this one (didn't delete it in case someone searches for "assume-unchanged" and "svn"):
[SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the `svn:ignore` property.

Assuming that you're running Windows and that you've installed TortoiseSVN:
Right-click the folder that contains the code you have checked out and select "TortoiseSVN" --> "Properties".

This will bring up a new dialog where you can add or edit the properties currently associated with your repository. Add or edit the `svn:ignore` property and adjust it so that it references the file you want to exclude from accidental commits.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can ignore files. I want the file to be versioned though, but I do not want to commit certain changes for the duration of a development session, if you know what I mean. In Git you can ignore files, but you can also mark them with the "assume-unchanged" flag. https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#ignoring-versioned-files I will update my question to make it clear.

Comment: Ah, well in that case you could add it to an ignore list in subversion. From the commit dialog in TortoiseSVN, right-click the files that's listed as changed and select "Add to ignore list" and select a pattern that suits your situation. NB: this will only be honored on your own machine. Your colleagues machines won't have this restriction.

Comment: I believe that adding the file pattern to a local ignore list will only have an effect on files which are not yet versioned. By the way, I use CornerStone on OSX. And I suppose that TurtoiseSVN will not enable the "Add to ignore list" option for files already versioned. Have you tried to ignore files which are already versioned?

Comment: For files that are already versioned you can add them to a so called change list that in TortoiseSVN is called "ignore-on-commit". That will result in the file not being checked when you bring up the commit dialog, where as all other files are checked and thus prepared to be committed.

Comment: Too bad I do not use TurtoiseSVN : [

Comment: Turns out that what you're looking for in your SVN client has been requested for almost four years. http://zennaware.uservoice.com/forums/6726-cornerstone/suggestions/85675-add-changelist-support Perhaps time to turn to command line?