# Best Practices for Sharing Eclipse Launchconfigurations

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, configuration, launch

This might be considered a minor thing, but I'm curious how you typicially solve following situation (if this is even a common use case): We have a project with dozens of practical Launch-Configurations for everyday use. Depending on which part of the application you work with, different launch configurations are interesting. To filter these, we use the favourite setting of eclipse. Those, who are needed where added to favourites, others removed.

Unfortunatly the favourite state is written within the launch configuration file, so SVN recognizes changing the favourite state as a change, when synchronizing a project. Since everyone usually needs different launch configurations at a specific time, this isn´t considered a desired behaviour.

Is there any way to work around this? How do you typically manage your launch configurations for a project?

Comment: So if the specifications in this file are just changing for personal use and nothing realy relevant to your project - why not add it to the ignore-list? we are creating basic-files for all and then add it to ignore because everyone and safe commands/styles/configs/... like he/she want. I ever shought this is the classic-way.

Comment: because initially, when checking the project out, we want them to be part of the sources, so you don't have to create those from scratch. As soon as a file is checked in, its not possible to put it on ignore-list, is it?

Comment: Create app.config.template and check in this to svn and rename it to app.config which is ignored or edit the changelist so since this commands the file is ignored on changes but checkt in as usual [example entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit/635787#635787)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to **share only a few and only very important launch configurations** that are marked **as** to be displayed in a **favorites** menu (see *Common* tab in the launch configuration):

To **add a shared launch configuration** to the **personal favorites** menu, you have following options:

- Add the shared launch configuration to the favorites menu but **do not commit the changed `.launch` file**
- **Duplicate** the launch configuration and change ***Save As*** to ***Local File*** (see *Common* tab)
- **Wrap** the shared launch configuration **in a new Launch Group** launch configuration

Alternatively, **launch configurations** can also be shared **in a separate repository**, outside of the associated project.