# Base version of an ignored file in SVN

Tags: svn

Currently I know that there is a way in SVN to not check in a file at all (or remove it from the repository) and then put it to ignore list.

Is it possible to have a "base" version of a file under its final name (not the renamed one) in SVN and then ignore all local changes made by any developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The file is either ignored or not. Since the file was already added into  Subversion, adding its name or name pattern to `svn:ignore` won't make SVN ignore local modifications of the file.

The `svn:ignore` and global ignores do not affect versioned files (that have been already added into the repository).

However, if you are using TortoiseSVN, perhaps the [`ignore-on-commit` changelist](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-ignore) will help you:

> Any file added to this changelist will automatically be unchecked in
> the commit dialog. You can still commit changes, but you have to
> select it manually in the commit dialog.

Also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635446/761095).